# OpenACC - Missing end data region block

Tags: c++, typedef, openacc

I have error "Missing end data region block" when compiling with

pgc++ -mp -ta=tesla:cuda9.1 -Minfo=accel figure.cpp mesh.cpp main.cpp

I have this program and I use PGI 18.4

```
//////////////////figure.h
#include <iostream>
class figure;
typedef double(figure::*FuncPtr)(double, double);
class figure
{
    public:
    figure(void);
    ~figure(void);
    #pragma acc routine seq
    double sum(double u, double v);
};
//////////////////figure.cpp
#include "figure.h"
figure::figure(void)
{
    #pragma acc enter data create(this)
}
figure::~figure(void)
{
    #pragma acc exit data delete(this)
}
double figure::sum(double u, double v)
{
return u + v;   
}
//////////////////mesh.h
#include "figure.h"
class Mesh{
public:
    double u,v;
    figure* m_Figure;
    #pragma acc routine seq
    void SetFun(void);
    void get();
    Mesh();
    ~Mesh();
};
//////////////////mesh.cpp
#include "mesh.h"
FuncPtr X;
#pragma omp threadprivate(X)
Mesh::Mesh(void)
{
    #pragma acc enter data create(this)
    #pragma acc enter data create(m_Figure[0:1])
}
Mesh::~Mesh(void)
{   
    #pragma acc exit data delete(m_Figure[0:1])
    #pragma acc exit data delete(this)
}
void Mesh::SetFun(void)
{
X = &figure::sum;
}
void Mesh::get(void)
{   
    int N = 5;
    Mesh ObjNew;
    ObjNew.u = 23;
    ObjNew.v = 48;
    ObjNew.SetFun();
    std::cout << (m_Figure->*X)(ObjNew.u,ObjNew.v) << std::endl;
    #pragma acc parallel loop copyin(N) copy(ObjNew,m_Figure[0:1]) private(X)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            ObjNew.SetFun();
            (m_Figure->*X)(i*i,i);
        }
    }
}
//////////////////main.cpp
#include "mesh.h"
int main(){
    Mesh Obj;
    Obj.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So the problem in typedef? Or maybe something else?
I also trying to compile with -Minfo = all option, but don't get nothing new about problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing an error about a missing ending data block but rather an error about statics not allowed in an OpenACC routine.  The basic issue being that function pointers aren't supported on the device so you wont be able to call "SetFun" in device code nor call the function pointer.